# How can I get ubuntu 22.04 to fit window size in OTABox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed an Ubuntu 22.04 VM in VirtualBox 6.1.34 on a windows 11 OS and everything is working correctly, but I am unable to get it to fit the screen.

I have tried:

- Installing VBox Guest Additions:

I started by running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
and then inserted image: Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image
opened the disk and ran `./autorun.sh`
Then I rebooted the VM and nothing changed

- Using VBoxSVGA for a Graphics Controller

I shut down my VM and went to settings and added RAM and Video Memory, disabled Nested paging (in System->Acceleration->Hardware Virtualization), and changed the graphics controller from VMSVGA to VBoxSVGA.

I then started the VM and was unable to move the cursor, and my user doesn't show up to sign in.

Here are the settings for the VM:

[image]

This is the Ubuntu Login screen:

[image]

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!